# Need to a function or any way of making 1 image a featured from the image set

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So I have these 2 models (Product and ProductImages models) and I want the user to be able to select from the images, a featured image of his/her choice from the many uploaded images (ProductImages model) and this will be reflected in the template as a featured image for that product.

Product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField("About", max_length=400)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categories", blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField("Order", default=0)
    featured = models.BooleanField("Featured", default=False)


    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

ProductImage

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
    productimages = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/product")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

This can be a function that will help to enable the user select the profile image of their choice. What do you think?
will be grateful for your response

Comment: What is exactly the question here? You already have a boolean field named `featured`. Just give the user a way to set it to `True`.

Comment: Well, you need to understand the usual workflow of django. You need to setup a template that shows the images, a POST request from this template to a URL that is connected to views.py, which gives you the selected image, and then you should change the `featured` value in the model int he views.py. If you don't know how to do it, I recommend diving into the tutorials here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/    Good luck!